# Image Magick align text points based on number of text points

Tags: php, image, algorithm, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Is it possible to get somehow the width of a text which one draws in image magick?

My current convert command looks like this:

> convert -size 720x480 -background #000 xc:black -fill white -stroke
>   white \
>   -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text 72,370 'NavP1'" \ 
>   -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text , ''" \
>   -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text , ''" \
>   -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text 370,370 'Extras'" \ 
>   -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text 430,370 'opt'" \ 
>   -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text 550,370 'NavP1'" \ C:\xampp\htdocs\labelText.bmp

I did this programmatically and want to center and align the navigation points to each other based on how many navigation points I have

( I get the number of navigation points from my php formular / database ).

Here is a little sketch of what I mean and how it should look like

```
________________________________________
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|             navp1  navp2              |
|_______________________________________|

________________________________________
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|         navp1  navp2  navp3           |
|_______________________________________|
```

I have a fixed width for that image (720px).

Thus I have a minimum number of 2 navigation points and a maximum number of 6 navigation points.

My thought is that if I could get the width of each Navigation (text/word) point I could calculate and align the points correctly.

But right know I could not find a function which does that.

I tried Mark Setchell Answer but my command seems to have a mistake

> convert -debug annotate -size 720x480 -background #000 xc:black -fill
>   white -stroke white \  -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text 72,370
>   'nav1'" \  -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text 180,370 'nav2'" \ 
>   -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text 430,370 'nav3'" \  -font Arial -pointsize 18 \ -draw "text 550,370 'nav4'" \ C:\xampp\htdocs\test.bmp

but I get following error message:

> no images defined '-background' @
>   error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/325

Comment: Can you simplify your command please? What is the point of all the `-size` settings, you don't need any of them other than the first as far as I can tell. Also, `-font`, and `-pointsize` are *"settings"*, just the same as `-fill` and `-stroke` so they remain set until changed so you can remove all but the first of them.

Comment: Ok I simplified it a bit hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't work because `#` is a comment character, so you need to escape or quote it - or just use `black`

Comment: ok that did that error now I get this: unable to open iamge '\': no such file or directory @ error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand what you are looking for, but I think that getting the font metrics will maybe help. Try this and look for all the numbers you want in the line commencing "Metrics:":

```
convert -debug annotate -size 720x480 -background red xc:black -fill white -stroke white -font Arial -pointsize 18 -draw "text 82,370 'Nav P1'" a.png
```

**Output**

```
2016-06-03T09:50:12+01:00 0:00.010 0.010u 6.9.4 Annotate convert[85474]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1421/Annotate
  Font /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 18
2016-06-03T09:50:12+01:00 0:00.020 0.010u 6.9.4 Annotate convert[85474]: annotate.c/GetTypeMetrics/843/Annotate
  Metrics: text: Nav P1; width: 58; height: 21; ascent: 16; descent: -4; max advance: 36; bounds: 1.95312,0  6.70312,14; origin: 59,0; pixels per em: 18,18; underline position: -4.5625; underline thickness: 2.34375
2016-06-03T09:50:12+01:00 0:00.020 0.010u 6.9.4 Annotate convert[85474]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1421/Annotate
  Font /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 18
```

Comment: I was wondering that output probably does show only in the command line, do you know how to print that as an "echo" so to say, like on my browser

Comment: Your browser? If you are writing PHP for a web-based application, you can query the font metrics in **PHP Imagick** and have all the control in the world... http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php - I still don't understand what you are actually trying to do!

Comment: SO basically my web application gets input data and with that data I try to built an image, my problems lies currently on how to create and align the navigation points. Based on the user input I run a convert command.
Hope you did understand it now:)

Comment: I have edited my question may you have a look at the command I cannot find the mistake